# Input type text array jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to php and jquery. I want validation for input type text.

```
<input type="text" size="5" name="add_qnty[]" value="">
```

I have tried the server side scripting but no use. So please help me 
so that my submit will redirect only if all textboxes will fill with data.

Comment: don't ever think to avoid server side validation; feel free to add frontend validation, of course, there are plenty of tutorial on the net for this (we can't really help you if you don't provide the code you're using)

Comment: Try using this link [Basic Validation](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/basic-jquery-validation-form/). and as Damien Pirsy said you need server side validation also but it works only after you submit use both

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').each(function(){ if($(this).val() == ''){return false;} });`

Comment: Why not use the `required` attribute on the input elements? Then the browser will do this check automatically.

Comment: Then SOME browsers will do this check depending on DOCTYPE

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.Barmar I have enter required and code is working thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add 'class=required' to all the required fields in the form and send these fields as an array to the below function like:

```
       checkFrmFill( $( "#formid").find(".required"));
```

and the function will be:

```
        function checkFrmFill(inputs) {

            var returnVal = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].type == "text" && inputs[i].value == "") {
                    returnVal = false;
                } else if (inputs[i].tagName == "SELECT" && ( inputs[i].value == "select" ||  inputs[i].value == 0 ) || inputs[i].value == "" || inputs[i].value == null) {
                    returnVal = false;
                } else if (inputs[i].type == "password" && inputs[i].value == "") {
                    returnVal = false;
                } else if (inputs[i].type == "textarea" && inputs[i].value == "") {
                    returnVal = false;
                }
              }
              return returnVal;
          }
```

This will return false for those fields that are blank.

Answer (score 0):

For every text input add required attribute at the end of the tag.

```
   <input type="text" size="5" name="add_qnty[]" value="" required> 
   <input type="text" size="5" name="add_qnty[]" value="" required>
```

refer http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Answer (score 0):

HTML

...........................

form id ='frm'

submit button id ='submit_frm'

SCRIPT

.............................

$(function(){

$('#submit_frm').click(function(){

$('#frm').find('em.err').remove();

```
$('#frm').find('input[type=text]').each(function(){

  if($(this).val()==''){

     $(this).parent().append('<em class="err">This field is required</em>');

  }

});

if($('#frm').find('em.err').length > 0 ){

  return false;

}else{

    return true;

}
```

});

});

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Working Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bprLs121/)

```
$("form").on("submit",function(){
    var len = $("input[name='add_qnty[]']").filter(function() {
        return !this.value; 
    }).addClass("has-error").length;
    alert(len);
    if(len == 0){
        return true; // Submit form
    } else {
        return false; // Validation failed
    }
})
```